# .map() sobre un array de objetos multinivel

Tags: reactjs, object, map

tengo un objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```
{1:[{1:1, 2:2 ...}, {1:1, 2:2 ...},...]   2:[{1:1, 2:2 ...}, {1:1, 2:2 ...}, ..]}
```

quiero referenciar a la primer o segunda propiedad en un react component stateless con una prop y hacer map para renderizar el componente 
de que forma puedo referenciar a la primera o segunda propiedad?

```
<div id='drum-pads'>{Object.keys(o).map(d => (
          <Pad
            key={d.name}
            id={d.name}
            letter={d.shortcut}
            src={d.link}
            handleDisplay={props.handleDisplay}
          />   
         ))}
        </div>
```

Comment: Agrega mas informacion sobre lo que deseas hacer y estructura mejor tu publicacion remarcando el codigo

Comment: listo, gracias por tu apreciacion!

Answer (score 0):

en lugar de usar Object.keys(o) (si puedes usar el standard ECMAScript ES2017) puedes usar Object.values(o) para poder acceder las propiedades de tu objeto.

```
Object.values(o).map(d => (
      <Pad
        key={d[n].name}
        id={d[n].name}
        letter={d[n].shortcut}
        src={d[n].link}
        handleDisplay={props.handleDisplay}
      />   
     ));
```

Puedes usar tambien.

```
Object.keys(o).map(d => (
      <Pad
        key={o[d][n].name}
        id={o[d][n].name}
        letter={o[d][n].shortcut}
        src={o[d][n].link}
        handleDisplay={props.handleDisplay}
      />   
     ));
```

Siendo n la enesima propiedad del array que quieras acceder (la primera o la segunda en tu pregunta).

Comment: Serviría mucho que dieras un ejemplo práctico de lo que mencionas en tu respuesta :)